# I need help properly encrypting my computer SSD

Tags: encryption, windows, data-leakage, veracrypt, ssd

My main laptop recently broke down and i've been forced to use an older laptop I had in storage.

This machine was encrypted years ago with veracrypt and only has an SSD. It's around 250 GB of storage.

I've learned more about cryptography over the years, and using this machine right now, i'm faced with a few serious issues I cannot solve.

First of all, I cannot remember if I encrypted this SSD before any data was stored on it or after.

Second of all, the version of windows I am running on is extremely outdated (1903). This is a major security issue. I was UNABLE to upgrade or update with the veracrypt bootloader present. This means I am going to have to decrypt the entire drive and upgrade then rencrypt.

Due to how SSD's work, I am now going crazy trying to figure out how to encrypt this thing so that forensic analysis won't be able to get any leaked information from the drive.

My threat level is moderate. Not a three letter agency but let's say for the sake of this thread that my threat level is local police and their forensics lab.

How do I do this? I don't have any other laptop to use at the moment so I can't even figure out how to wipe this thing properly in place on this current machine.

Obviously decrypting and upgrading then simply encrypting will do absolutely nothing for me because of overprovisioning.

What do I do?

Comment: Is the data contained on the SSD worth more or less than a new SSD? Most of the time, buying a new SSD is the best course of action.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have exceeded my current budget and cannot buy a new one. I'd rather buy a new one and destroy the current one, but I cannot. Is there any other way to absolutely make sure that my sensitive files are safe, like with an HDD?

Comment: The only way to be absolutely sure is to destroy the SSD.

Comment: Depending on the manufacturer, they may have a [secure erase utility](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/secure-erase-ssd-or-hard-drive) that would erase the over provisioning chips, too.

Comment: My SSD is quite old (SanDisk sd8sn8u 256g 1006) and I cannot find a special program for it. As far as I know, you can directly command your SSD to secure erase but if Windows is on the SSD, then how can I get all of this done if I only have one laptop? How do I know it's been done?

Comment: iPhone erases all information by just overwriting a master key that is stored in encrypted form in two locations. (With some specialised software support for guaranteed overwriting and destruction of existing data).